# What is the equivalent of 'whole wheat flour' in Russian?

Tags: перевод, выбор-имени

In American English the standard term seems to be 'whole wheat flour', while in British English it seems that whole meal and whole wheat are used interchangeably (or perhaps whole meal refers to coarse whole wheat flour).
How would 'whole wheat flour' be written on Russian flour products? Or how would you ask for it in a Russian supermarket? 
When I search on some Chinese retail sites I've seen products labelled "пшеничная мука" being listed in Chinese as 'whole wheat flour' but from what I can gather it only means 'wheat flour' in Russian. Is that the same as 'whole wheat flour' in English?

Comment: I know nothing about wheat and flour, but look for starters [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0) (if you can read Russian). It appears there are different quality levels of wheat flour in Russian nomenclature.

Comment: I suppose I have seen the term "мука из цельной пшеницы" though I admit I have no idea what it means.

Comment: a list of possible equivalents in Multitran - https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=whole%20wheat%20flour

Comment: @Viridianus means hull is also there during processing, so there would be more fiber and less digestable carbs.

Answer (score 8):

The equivalent "vulgar" term will be [цельнозерновая мука](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0) (whole-grain flour). More proper term will be **обойная мука**, while any one or both of these terms [may be present on a package](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0&tbm=isch).

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge "whole wheat floor" is actually "**непросеянная (пшеничная) мука**". According to the definition from [this](http://namnamra.com/ingredient/625-muka-neproseyannaya) site:

> **Непросеянная мука** или **мука грубого помола** - это мука сделанная из
>   цельных зерен. Чаще всего под непросеянной мукой подразумевают грубую
>   пшеничную муку, но на самом деле её производят из любых видов злаковых
>   культур. Характерной особенностью такой муки является темный цвет и
>   большое содержание грубых частиц.

Which is exactly what "whole wheat floor" is. 
The other reason I think this is the right term is that whole wheat bread is called in Polish ["Chleb razowy"](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chleb_razowy) and it just happened that I now that this relates to `мука разового помола` which the other term for `мука грубого помола`.

Also I want to add that the answer provided ("обойная мука") does not contradict to my answer - it's just that as far as I know "обойная мука" is a kind of "мука грубого помола", it's one of its varieties. Here's relevant [quote](https://vchemraznica.ru/v-chem-raznica-mezhdu-obdirnoj-i-obojnoj-mukoj/):

> Это распространенный сорт, который представляет собой порошок **самого
>   грубого помола**. Зерно размалывают, иногда даже не просеивая, поэтому
>   встречаются достаточно крупные частички до 700 мкм.

As a side-note - there's a difference [between](http://npg-belovodie.ru/content/view/58/31/) "цельнозерновая мука" and "мука грубого помола".